# Brace needs to be escaped with \ inside single quotes

Tags: bash

I expect the following to work:

```
ls -l | grep '^.{38}<some date>'
```

It should give me the files which have said date in modification time. But it does not work. The following works:

```
ls -l | grep '^.\{38\}<some date>'
```

Isn't `'...'` supposed to turn off special meaning for all the meta characters? Why should we have to escape braces?

Comment: The quotes escape the braces from the *shell*; they still have special meaning in the regular expression once `grep` parses it.

Comment: BTW, as an aside, searching for files made on a specific date is a job for `find`, not `grep`ing `ls`; see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) discussing why trying to parse `ls` output is error-prone.

Comment: Thank you everyone for responding to it. It was just out of curiosity that I tried this command and it wouldn't work without escaping braces. So, it's clear now that for grep we need to escape braces for them to have special meaning. So far I'd used python, perl, etc REs and there I didn't have to escape braces for them to have special meaning. Once again thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `.{38}`, as interpreted here by `grep`, matches an arbitrary string of exactly 38 characters. To match literal braces, you need to escape them.

```
.\{38\}
```

In order to ensure that *that* exact 7-character sequence is seen by `grep`, you need to quote the string so that the *shell* doesn't perform quote removal and reduce it to `.{38}` before `grep` gets a chance to see it.

---

Misunderstanding the question, it appears `grep` is using *basic* regular expressions, in which unescaped braces are the literal characters and the escaped ones introduce a brace expression. In *extended* regular expressions, it's the other way around. In either case, though, the single quotes are protecting all enclosed characters from special treatment by the *shell*; whether `grep` treats them specially is another question.

Comment: I don't want to match literal braces. The RE is any 38 characters and then date. (On my system ls -l output's date starts at column 39). The bash documentation says that '...' turns off special meaning for all meta characters. So why isn't braces passed to grep as such?

Comment: Ah, your version of `grep` must be using basic regular expressions, in which `{` and `}` match literal braces, and `\{...\}` is a brace expression.

Comment: @SRK, ...keep in mind that external tools (like `grep`) have no way of knowing what quoting or escaping was or wasn't used at the shell level -- the *only thing* they can see is the literal C strings placed on that tool's argument vector. A program started by the shell doesn't know if a literal backslash in its argument list was in single-quotes previously -- all it knows is that the backslash is still there (which is to say, that it *wasn't* consumed by the shell as a subset of the shell's own syntax).

Comment: Thank you. It's well understood now.

Answer (score 1):

There are many variants of regular expression syntax. By default, `grep` uses the "basic" ("BRE" or "obsolete") regular expression syntax, in which braces must be escaped to be treated as repetition bounds (what you're trying to do here); without the escapes, they're treated as just literal characters. In the "extended" ("ERE" or "modern"), Perl-compatible ("PCRE"), and ... well, pretty much all other variants, it's the other way around: escaped braces are treated as literal characters, and unescaped ones define repetition bounds.

```
grep '^.{38}<some date>'      # Matches any character followed by literal braces around "38"
grep '^.\{38\}<some date>'    # Matches 38 characters
grep -E '^.{38}<some date>'   # Matches 38 characters (-E invokes "extended" syntax)
egrep '^.{38}<some date>'     # Matches 38 characters (egrep uses "extended" syntax)
```

BTW, parentheses are the same: literal unless escaped in the basic syntax, literal *if* escaped in the extended syntax. And there are a few other differences; see [the re_format man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/re_format/). There are also many other syntax variants (Perl-compatible, etc). It's important to know what variant the tool you're using accepts, and format your RE appropriately for it.

BTW2, as @Charles Duffy pointed out in a comment, [parsing `ls` output isn't a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In this case, the number of characters before the date will depend on the width of other fields (user, group, size), which will *not* be consistent, so skipping 38 characters might skip part of the date field *or* not skip enough. You'd be much better off using something like `find` with the `-mtime` or `-mmin` tests, or at least using `stat` instead of `ls` (since you can control the fields with the format string, and e.g. put the date at the beginning of the line) (but `stat` will still have some of `ls`'s other problems).